# Facebook App show blank in PC chrome, but work in phone's chrome

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-apps

I wrote a facebook app.
     https://apps.facebook.com/nusquare-free/ 
     It shows blank page in PC chrome for https://apps.facebook.com/nusquare-free/
     But it works in mobile phone chroma, safari and PC safari.
     When I direct to http://nuphoto.com.tw/freemobile/  -->This is my web page for facebook APP.
     It works for every browser, including PC browser.

Could you tell me how to make it work for PC chrome when directly connect to 
    https://apps.facebook.com/nusquare-free/   ?

Is this because my web site is not SSL authenticated ? or the setting problems ?
     But it works on cellphone(iphone and android).
     Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it's because https/ SSL certification problem.
After I apply a issued SSL certification and install it in my server. It's solved.